# Sorting by 2 fields in ksh

Tags: text-processing, scripting, ksh, sort

```
file-
xyz.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 195G 150G 57% /home
xyz.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 197G 148G 58% /home
xyz.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 201G 145G 59% /home
xyz.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 218G 129G 63% /home
xyz.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 223G 124G 65% /home
xyz.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 226G 121G 66% /home
xyz.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 210G 136G 61% /home
xyz.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 220G 127G 64% /home
xyz.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 173G 171G 51% /home

Result
xyz.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 201G 145G 59% /home
xyz.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 226G 121G 66% /home
xyz.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 220G 127G 64% /home
```

For every first column that contains sorted date, group by first column and display only the row that contains fifth column with maximum %.

Here's what I have tried,however I can't get the desired output. Anyone can help me?

```
awk -F, '{if ((a[substr($1,5,6)] == substr($1,5,6)) && (b[substr($5,1,2)] < substr($5,1,2)))b[substr($5,1,2)]=substr($5,1,2);}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i];}}' test.txt
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange, what have you tried so far to achieve this ?

Comment: No. Any examples or help I can get here?

Comment: Worth popping that into original question with the formatting to make it more readable please

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with, doubt it's the most effective way and would like to see something more efficient. However, it does the job

```
sort test.txt | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | uniq > unique.txt

while read p; do
  grep $p test.txt | sort -r -k5 | head -1
done < unique.txt
rm unique.txt
```

Explanation:

`sort test.txt | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | uniq > unique.txt` 
extract all unique file name from the list

`grep $p test.txt | sort -r -k5 | head -1` sort based on the 5th field (which has the %value) on descending order and print only the first line.

Comment: +1: Your use of `-k` in `sort` led to my answer, as I originally was about to post an almost identical but slightly more bloated answer

Answer (score 1):

This works under `ksh` for me:

```
sort -nrk5 -t ' ' test.txt | sort -t '.' -unk2
```

Given this test file:

- ```
  otherfile_.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 55% /home
  somefile_.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 45% /home
  file71.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 71% /home
  file_longer_12.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 78% /home
  qwerty_.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 31% /home
  xyz.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 34% /home
  abcdef.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 85% /home
  hellojoe_.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 45% /home
  kitchen_.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 39% /home
  room.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 95% /home
  rooftop_77.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 12% /home
  f.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 30% /home
  ```

This is the result:

- ```
  file_longer_12.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 78% /home
  abcdef.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 85% /home
  room.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 000G 000G 000G 95% /home
  ```

Therefore it allows for filenames that:

- Have differing lengths
- Contain numeric characters

**Breakdown:**

- `sort -nrk5 -t ' '` : Initially sort by percentage in column 5
- `sort -t '.' -unk2` : Print unique results, only counting the date string from the first field (using a `.` separator)

Comment: you could use the `-r` in the first sort itself instead of piping it to the second one. Should achieve the same result. And upvoted, definitely a better resolution than mine..

Comment: However, I see a problem with the `-w10` what if the filenames aren't of the same length. The user posted it as `xyz` for all, but what if there were file names with different lengths, eg `qwerty`

Comment: @debal - Thanks - answer amended now using `sort` instead

Comment: Thanks. Somehow, I got the output not exactly in the highest% for each group, but the lowest%.

Answer (score 0):

how about this awk

```
awk -F"[.: ]" '{if($(NF-1)+0>Arr[$2]+0){Arr[$2]=$(NF-1)+0;Res[$2]=$0}}END{for (i in Res){print Res[i]}}' file
xyz.161210:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 226G 121G 66% /home
xyz.161211:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 220G 127G 64% /home
xyz.161209:/userlogs/logs/reports 355G 201G 145G 59% /home


awk -F"[.: ]" '{
if($(NF-1)+0>Arr[$2]+0)
{
   Arr[$2]=$(NF-1)+0;
    Res[$2]=$0
}
}
END{
for (i in Res)
{
print Res[i]
}
}' file
```